# ":first-of-type" works, ":last-of-type" doesn't

Tags: jquery, html, css, pseudo-class

The following ":first-of-type" works for me, but the ":last-of-type" won't.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>

.wrapper .item:first-of-type {
    background-color: blue;
}
.wrapper .item:last-of-type {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Even when counting the number of elements via jQuery, I receive the following results:

```
$('.wrapper .item').size(); // equals 3
$('.wrapper .item:first-of-type').size(); // equals 1
$('.wrapper .item:last-of-type').size(); // equals 0
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both work fine for me, but you should be aware that *jQuery doesn't support `first-of-type` and `last-of-type`.*

They only work at all because `querySelectorAll` supports them. So browsers that don't support `qSA` will break.

---

By the way, your `0` result comes from the fact that `first/last-of-type` considers the element type, even though you only specified the class. My testing was a little different.

Comment: I was just using jQuery to test; I'm only worried about the CSS. However I still cannot get the ":last-of-type" to work. For the specific example you can look here - http://apps.ryanprentiss.com/osiris/?m=20111218.

In the style.css there is a ".archiveWrapper .archiveItem:last-of-type" style that simply will not register. When changed to ":first-of-type", it works.

Comment: @RyanPrentiss: Yeah check out the last sentence in the answer. The `-of-type` selectors will take into consideration the *type* of element. If you change your `<div class="shadow"></div>` to something like `<p class="shadow"></p>`, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't support `:last-of-type` - http://selectivizr.com/ - look at the libraries comparison table. You might want to look at this plugin to help you - https://github.com/keithclark/JQuery-Extended-Selectors

Comment: I was just using jQuery to test; I'm only worried about the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) and [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/)? The former selects the first element in the matched set and the latter the last element.

[Here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5543) is a bug report pertaining to `:first` and `:last-of-type`.

Comment: I was just using jQuery to test; I'm only worried about the CSS.